# Add ‘Chapter’ beginning on the Title in the Second Language Content

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, titles, languages, chinese

I'm writing an essay of which content should be showed in Chinese and English. The Chinese content is showed perfect as the main language, but the English content cannot show the 'Chapter' at the beginning of each title of chapter.

Mine(wrong)

**[image]Others(Correct)**

[image]

Only Chapter needs this, while Section or subsection do not need this.

In my main page:

```
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents

\maketableofcontents  %Chinese 

\tableofengcontents    %English 
\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

In the definition of content page:

```
%—————————English Contents—————————————
\makeatletter
\newcommand\engcontentsname{Contents}
\newcommand\tableofengcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\engcontentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\engcontentsname}{\MakeUppercase\engcontentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toe}% !!!!Define a new contents!!!!
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\newcommand\addengcontents[2]{%
    \addcontentsline{toe}{#1}{\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}#2}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\echapter[1]{\addengcontents{chapter}{#1}}
\newcommand\esection[1]{\addengcontents{section}{#1}}
\newcommand\esubsection[1]{\addengcontents{subsection}{#1}}
\newcommand\esubsubsection[1]{\addengcontents{subsubsection}{#1}}
%—————————English Contents—————————————
```

I suppose the 'Chapter' should be inserted in the somewhere above?

If anyone could help me.
Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

The `tocloft` package can help, read the documentation (`texdoc tocloft`).

After the end of your `English Contents` add

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter } % put Chapter before number
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{4em} % Extra space for Chapter
```

This worked with my rendering of your code into an MWE (shown below) which of course didn't process `\maketableofcontents` as you had shown no code for that. I have no idea about your Chinese chapter titles if they will be affected.

```
% engchintocprob.tex  SE 539522

\documentclass{report}

%—————————English Contents—————————————
\makeatletter
\newcommand\engcontentsname{Contents}
\newcommand\tableofengcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\engcontentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\engcontentsname}{\MakeUppercase\engcontentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toe}% !!!!Define a new contents!!!!
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\newcommand\addengcontents[2]{%
    \addcontentsline{toe}{#1}{\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}#2}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\echapter[1]{\addengcontents{chapter}{#1}}
\newcommand\esection[1]{\addengcontents{section}{#1}}
\newcommand\esubsection[1]{\addengcontents{subsection}{#1}}
\newcommand\esubsubsection[1]{\addengcontents{subsubsection}{#1}}
%—————————English Contents—————————————

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{4em}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents
\maketableofcontents  %Chinese 

\tableofengcontents    %English 
\cleardoublepage
\echapter{First}

\end{document}
```